# Mysql refusing to complete certain commands, returns with endless '<'

Tags: mysql

mysql - 5.7

apache 2.2

Ubuntu 18.04

Some of my mysql commands are not completing. I get an endless return value of "<". For example:

I am logged in as 'root'.

> CREATE USER ‘name’@‘localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
>
> '>
>
> '>

I can't complete certain commands. Any ideas what is causing this?

I have purged mysql and reinstalled. Problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters are included in your query. It looks like, when you copied the query from somewhere, these special characters came into the picture. Just try to type those characters using your keyboard. That's it!

Answer (score 3):

Look closely! You have a weird mix of quotation marks there; some are "smart quotes" and so you're getting yourself stuck inside quote mode.

[image: Bugs highlighted]

The command-line interface is waiting for you to complete the quoted text that it deems to have begun just after the word "pass" (the previous quoted text was effectively `IDENTIFIED BY`).

[image: Bad quote #1]

[image: Bad quote #2]

[image: Good quote]

No need to reinstall MySQL - just use your keyboard to type these simple commands using the normal apostrophe button, rather than copy/pasting from websites that may reformat them.

---

> I am logged in as 'root'.

Generally unwise. Create yourself an account that has just the permissions you need for a specific kind of task, and use that.